# How can I get the GoudyIn package to work?

Tags: luatex, texlive, latexmk, tlmgr

I have installed the *initials* package with *tlmgr* but when I compile my doc with *latexmk* it doesn't find the fonts.

This is the error I get:

> '! LaTeX Error: File `GoudyIn.sty' not found.'

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{GoudyIn}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{royalblue}\GoudyInfamily{}}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{I}{n}!

\end{document}
```

Comment: This package is part of https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GoudIn`  package is part of [ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cfr-initials)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{RoyalBlue}\GoudyInfamily}


\begin{document}

\lettrine{I}{t is a little bit strange} driving on the opposite side of the road in Ireland, but you'll get used to it in a while.

\end{document}
```